# Spring Integration Jms channel with queue name from properties file

Tags: spring-integration

How to bind multiple queues names from property file to Spring POJO MDBs and connect all of them into one channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about JMS, you need a separate `<int-jms:message-driven-adapter/>` for each queue, but they can all send their messages to the same `channel`.

If you have a fixed number of queues, simply define the adapter for each with a property placeholder.

If you have a variable number of queues, you would need to create the adapters programmatically - you can create a child context for each with the single channel being in the parent context.

JMS (unlike AMQP/RabbitMQ) doesn't permit a consumer to consume from multiple queues. With the amqp inbound adapter, just give it a list of queues or queue names.